# Function doesn't count first letter

Tags: python

I am building function to count how many operations to do to convert 1st word to 2nd

For now it's only for first str longer

```
def ok(str1, str2):
    if len(str1) > len(str2) or len(str1) == len(str2):
        for a in range(0, len(str1)):
            i = 0
            j = 0
            if str1[i] == str2[i]: i = i + 1 
            if str1[i] != str2[i]: i = i + 1; j = j + 1
        dif = len(str1) - len(str2)
        j = j + dif
        print(j)
```

When I pass arguments "yes","no" the output is 2
When I pass args "noes", "no" it is still 2.
Looks like first letter doesn't count. Why is that?

Comment: Did you hear about `>=`? ;)

Comment: You initialize i and j to 0 in _each_ iteration. Why?

Comment: and you iterate over `a` and do not use it in your loop at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you reset i and j in every loop iteration:

```py
def ok(str1, str2):
    if len(str1) >= len(str2):
        # this is before the loop (before first letter)
        i = 0
        j = 0
        for a in range(0, len(str1)):
            # this is in the loop, will be called for every letter:
            if str1[i] == str2[i]: i = i + 1 
            if str1[i] != str2[i]: i = i + 1; j = j + 1
        dif = len(str1) - len(str2)
        j = j + dif
        print(j)
```

Answer (score 2):

The general solution to the problem you are solving is called [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), which is solvable using Dynamic Programming:

```
def levenshtein(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) < len(s2):
        return levenshtein(s2, s1)

    # len(s1) >= len(s2)
    if len(s2) == 0:
        return len(s1)

    previous_row = range(len(s2) + 1)
    for i, c1 in enumerate(s1):
        current_row = [i + 1]
        for j, c2 in enumerate(s2):
            insertions = previous_row[j + 1] + 1 # j+1 instead of j since previous_row and current_row are one character longer
            deletions = current_row[j] + 1       # than s2
            substitutions = previous_row[j] + (c1 != c2)
            current_row.append(min(insertions, deletions, substitutions))
        previous_row = current_row
    
    return previous_row[-1]
```